# Error : Unable to open module file System Error &H80070002&

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a web based dynamic vb form which is of around 20,000 lines suddenly my system got shutdown due to power loss, When I reopened the system then I found my .vb file is only left with Hexadecimal-Binary kind of text as in the screen shot.

When I am running the code in Visual Studio it is running fine and show the form in web browser but I need to edit it as I am in development phase.

On opening the file in notepad it is showing blank page with lots of blank lines.

I have tried to recover using 'restoring previous versions' but I found 'There are no previous versions available'.
I also have tried to recover using 'Open system restore' in which I found a list of restore point but even after successful completion issue is remain same.

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCwlh.jpg)

Comment: The file is just filled with zeros. This usually happens if VS is interrupted during the saving procedure. Unless you have a non-corrupted backup then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: By the way restore points don't restore your files, only possibly installed applications or system modifications.

Comment: So this means that I have to write the whole code again.

Comment: Yes. There's pretty much no way for you to recover it since parts of the data have probably been overwritten by now.

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I didn't any solution for this problem.
I have some my code in distributed manner so I merge those pieces of code and wrote rest of the code.

If any body knows better solution than this, please share it.